# How can I make variable numbers horizontally and make a list?

Tags: python, list

So I have that `a` is

```
['2019313251', 'V', '11', '58', 'am']   
['2017393939', 'V', '12', '03']  
['2020123456', 'V', '13', '24'] 
['1997031312', 'V', '13', '25']
['2013313990', 'V', '13', '32', 'pm']
['2018423519', 'V', '14', '10', 'pm'] 
['2019313251', 'E', '2', '58', 'pm'] 
['2017393939', 'V', '3', '03']  
['2017393939', 'E', '3', '04'] 
['2019313251', 'E', '5', '48', 'pm']  
['2017313882', 'E', '17', '54']
```

and I want to get the values of `a[2]` for `'V'` and make a list with it.

```
if a[1] == "V":
    b = a[2]
    b = b.strip().split(' ')
```

I tried this code but the ouput is

```
['11']   
['12']
['13'] 
...
```

and so on. How can I make it horizontally and make a list to get a result like `['11', '12', '13', ...]`

Comment: ```c = []```, In your if statement last line: ```c.append(str(b))```

Comment: It would be better if you could add all of the code that's producing this output, not just 3 lines. Also, assuming your input is a list of lists, please show it like that and format it as a code block.

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = [['2019313251', 'V', '11', '58', 'am'],
     ['2017393939', 'V', '12', '03'],
     ['2020123456', 'V', '13', '24'],
     ['1997031312', 'V', '13', '25'],
     ['2013313990', 'V', '13', '32', 'pm'],
     ['2018423519', 'V', '14', '10', 'pm'],
     ['2019313251', 'E', '2', '58', 'pm'],
     ['2017393939', 'V', '3', '03'],
     ['2017393939', 'E', '3', '04'],
     ['2019313251', 'E', '5', '48', 'pm'],
     ['2017313882', 'E', '17', '54']]

output = [x[2] for x in a if x[1] == 'V']
print(output)
```

output is your result like ['11', '12', '13', ...]

Comment: I guess you should add a condition like `[output = [x[2] for x in a if x[1] == 'V']`

Comment: how can I make 'a' list of list without defining it like in your code?

Comment: @carlos if `a` is not in that format to begin with, what format is it in?

Comment: Like in the first format. I got an user input all in one time and obtained 11 lists for 'a'

Comment: @carlos , what is the datatype of 'a' ? Are you receiving all the list as string type in 'a' ?